# How to spllit laserscan data from lidar into sections and view them on rviz

Tags: ros, lidar

I was trying to split the laser scan range data into subcategories and like to publish each category into different laser topics.

to specify more, the script should get one topic as an input - /scan and the script should publish three topics as follow = scan1, scan2, scan3

is there a way to split the laser scan and publish back and look them on rviz

I tried the following

```
def callback(laser):
    current_time = rospy.Time.now()
    regions["l_f_fork"] = laser.ranges[0:288]
    regions["l_f_s"] = laser.ranges[289:576]
    regions["stand"] = laser.ranges[576:864]
    l.header.stamp = current_time
    l.header.frame_id = 'laser'
    l.angle_min = 0
    l.angle_max = 1.57
    l.angle_increment =0
    l.time_increment = 0
    l.range_min = 0.0
    l.range_max = 100.0
    l.ranges = regions["l_f_fork"]
    l.intensities = [0]

    left_fork.publish(l)

    # l.ranges = regions["l_f_s"]
    # left_side.publish(l)

    # l.ranges = regions["stand"]
    # left_side.publish(l)

rospy.loginfo("publishing new info")
```

I can see the different topics on rviz, but they are lies on the same line,

Answer (score 0):

### Tutorial

- The following code splits the LaserScan data into three equal sections:

  ```
  #! /usr/bin/env python3
  """
  Program to split LaserScan into three parts.
  """

  import rospy
  from sensor_msgs.msg import LaserScan


  class LaserScanSplit():
      """
      Class for splitting LaserScan into three parts.
      """

      def __init__(self):

          self.update_rate = 50
          self.freq = 1./self.update_rate

          # Initialize variables
          self.scan_data = []

          # Subscribers
          rospy.Subscriber("/scan", LaserScan, self.lidar_callback)

          # Publishers
          self.pub1 = rospy.Publisher('/scan1', LaserScan, queue_size=10)
          self.pub2 = rospy.Publisher('/scan2', LaserScan, queue_size=10)
          self.pub3 = rospy.Publisher('/scan3', LaserScan, queue_size=10)

          # Timers
          rospy.Timer(rospy.Duration(self.freq), self.laserscan_split_update)

      def lidar_callback(self, msg):
          """
          Callback function for the Scan topic
          """
          self.scan_data = msg

      def laserscan_split_update(self, event):
          """
          Function to update the split scan topics
          """

          scan1 = LaserScan()
          scan2 = LaserScan()
          scan3 = LaserScan()

          scan1.header = self.scan_data.header
          scan2.header = self.scan_data.header
          scan3.header = self.scan_data.header

          scan1.angle_min = self.scan_data.angle_min
          scan2.angle_min = self.scan_data.angle_min
          scan3.angle_min = self.scan_data.angle_min

          scan1.angle_max = self.scan_data.angle_max
          scan2.angle_max = self.scan_data.angle_max
          scan3.angle_max = self.scan_data.angle_max

          scan1.angle_increment = self.scan_data.angle_increment
          scan2.angle_increment = self.scan_data.angle_increment
          scan3.angle_increment = self.scan_data.angle_increment

          scan1.time_increment = self.scan_data.time_increment
          scan2.time_increment = self.scan_data.time_increment
          scan3.time_increment = self.scan_data.time_increment

          scan1.scan_time = self.scan_data.scan_time
          scan2.scan_time = self.scan_data.scan_time
          scan3.scan_time = self.scan_data.scan_time

          scan1.range_min = self.scan_data.range_min
          scan2.range_min = self.scan_data.range_min
          scan3.range_min = self.scan_data.range_min

          scan1.range_max = self.scan_data.range_max
          scan2.range_max = self.scan_data.range_max
          scan3.range_max = self.scan_data.range_max

          # LiDAR Range
          n = len(self.scan_data.ranges)

          scan1.ranges = [float('inf')] * n
          scan2.ranges = [float('inf')] * n
          scan3.ranges = [float('inf')] * n

          # Splitting Block [three equal parts]
          scan1.ranges[0 : n//3] = self.scan_data.ranges[0 : n//3]
          scan2.ranges[n//3 : 2*n//3] = self.scan_data.ranges[n//3 : 2*n//3]
          scan3.ranges[2*n//3 : n] = self.scan_data.ranges[2*n//3 : n]

          # Publish the LaserScan
          self.pub1.publish(scan1)
          self.pub2.publish(scan2)
          self.pub3.publish(scan3)

      def kill_node(self):
          """
          Function to kill the ROS node
          """
          rospy.signal_shutdown("Done")

  if __name__ == '__main__':

      rospy.init_node('laserscan_split_node')
      LaserScanSplit()
      rospy.spin()
  ```

- The following are screenshots of the robot and obstacles in the environment in Gazebo and RViz:

[image]
[image]

#### References:

- [ROS1 Python Boilerplate](https://gist.github.com/leander-dsouza/b30947639b78e7caeb58320caa72fa4f)
- [atreus](https://github.com/leander-dsouza/atreus)